# Chart js horizontal bars don't line up with the labels

Tags: chart.js

This is a self-contained chart js horizontal bar chart with a timeline on the X axis. You can open it in a browser to see what happens. As in the screenshot attached, the bars don't line up with the labels. There must be a simple way to fix that. Any help will be appreciated.

```
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
      }

      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
        background: white;
      }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
      <canvas id="log_chart" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            barPercentage: 0.8,
            categoryPercentage: 1,
            labels: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:05:02']
                },{
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:06:00', '2022-09-29T16:10:10']
                }]
            },{
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:10:00', '2022-09-29T16:15:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:17:00', '2022-09-29T16:20:10']
                }]
            },{
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:20:00', '2022-09-29T16:25:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:26:00', '2022-09-29T17:30:10']
                }]
            },{
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test4',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:30:00', '2022-09-29T16:35:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test4',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:37:00', '2022-09-29T16:40:10']
                }]
            }],
        },
        options: {
            animation: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    stacked: true,
                    time: {
                        unit: 'second'
                    },
                    min: new Date('2022-09-29T16:00:00'),
                    max: new Date('2022-09-29T16:45:00'),
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        minRotation: 90,
                        maxRotation: 90
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    yAlign: 'bottom',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => {
                            return context.dataset.labelData[context.dataIndex];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('log_chart'),
      config
    );

    // Instantly assign Chart.js version
    //const chartVersion = document.getElementById('log_chart_version');
    //chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;
</script>
`
```

I've searched the web for a solution but I still can't figure it out.

**Update:**

The following script does what I need expect the bars don't line up with the labels on the left. I need multiple bars on each row with a timeline at the bottom. I also need to set the background color on each bar as well as display a tooltip on each bar.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
      }

      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
        background: white;
      }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
      <canvas id="log_chart" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            <!-- labels: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'], -->
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(64, 224, 208, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(64, 224, 208, 255)',
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:06:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip1'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:18:00', '2022-09-29T16:25:10'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip2'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:31:00', '2022-09-29T16:50:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip3'
                }]
            }, {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 149, 237, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(100, 149, 237, 255)',
                borderWidth: 0,
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:03:03', '2022-09-29T16:13:06' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip4'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:16:03', '2022-09-29T16:30:06' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip5'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:35:51', '2022-09-29T16:48:54' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip6'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:49:51', '2022-09-29T16:58:54' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip7'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:20:37', '2022-09-29T16:20:40' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip8'
                }]
            }, {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(143, 188, 139, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgba( 64, 224, 208, 255)',
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:05:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip9'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:12:00', '2022-09-29T16:30:10'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip10'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:40:00', '2022-09-29T16:55:48'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip11'
                }]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            animation: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    stacked: true,
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute'
                    },
                    min: new Date('2022-09-29T16:00:00'),
                    max: new Date('2022-09-29T16:45:00'),
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 70,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        minRotation: -90,
                        maxRotation: -90
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    yAlign: 'bottom',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => {
                            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].tooltip;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('log_chart'),
      config
    );
</script>
```

Comment: The data and datasets configuration is unclear. It seems you want to have y scale as index axis but it's a linear scale (therefore needs numbers) but you are setting strings. Also not clear how you are using timestamps in array, it's not supported AFAIK. What's the result you are expecting?

Comment: I've updated my original post to show exactly what I'm looking for. I need a timeline at the bottom and labels on the left. I need to set the background color on the bars and add a tooltip for each bar. The only thing not working is that the bars don't line up with the labels on the left. Timestamps are supported by the adapter library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use 1 dataset instead of 1 for each label.
See snippet below if it was you are expecting.

```js
    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:05:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test1',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:06:00', '2022-09-29T16:10:10']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:10:00', '2022-09-29T16:15:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:17:00', '2022-09-29T16:20:10']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:20:00', '2022-09-29T16:25:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:26:00', '2022-09-29T17:30:10']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test4',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:30:00', '2022-09-29T16:35:02']
                }, {
                    y: 'Test4',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:37:00', '2022-09-29T16:40:10']
                }]
            }],
        },
        options: {
            animation: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    stacked: true,
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute'
                    },
                    min: new Date('2022-09-29T16:00:00'),
                    max: new Date('2022-09-29T16:45:00'),
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        minRotation: 90,
                        maxRotation: 90
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                y: {
                  type: 'category'
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    yAlign: 'bottom',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => {
                            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].x;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('log_chart'),
      config
    );
```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
      }

      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
        background: white;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
      <canvas id="log_chart" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my original post to show exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The new script does what I need expect the bars don't line up with the labels on the left. I need multiple bars on each row with a timeline at the bottom. I also need to set the background color on each bar as well as display a tooltip on each bar.

Comment: The bars are not aligned because you are using multiple dataset. If you use 1 dataset it should work. For tooltip and background color, it's not a problem because by scriptable option you can se the color you need.

Comment: Have a look to codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/GRwxBvW

Comment: Thank you so much user2057925. The codepen code is what I was looking for. Works perfectly.

Comment: There is one more issue though. The labels on the Y axis can have two lines of text. Using \n doesn't work. They always appear on two lines. I have tried using an array like this: y: ['Test1', 'line1'] but when I do none of the bars are showing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Set the Y label with a separator (like \n) and implement ticks.callback to split them and return as an array,

Comment: That doesn't work because the label is numeric (0, 1, 2) in ticks.callback. I've put it in plugins and it should work there but then for example the Y label becomes 'Test1' while the y value in the dataset is 'Test3\nline2' and since the two are now different strings nothing gets displayed, not even the bars.   plugins: [{
   beforeInit: function (chart) {
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function (e,i,a) {
     a[i] = e.y.split('\n')[0];
     console.log(e.y.split('\n')[0]);
    })
   }
  }]

Comment: The tick callback is giving you a numebr but it works because that number is the index of the label. Have a look to the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats As reported: The category axis, which is the default x-axis for line and bar charts, uses the index as internal data format. For accessing the label, use this.getLabelForValue(value). API: getLabelForValue

Comment: Now I get it. It finally works! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user2057925, I was able to make it work. Here's the complete code.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
      }

      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
        background: white;
      }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
      <canvas id="log_chart" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const colors = {
      'Test1\nline2': 'rgba(64, 224, 208, 255)',
      'Test2\nline2': 'rgba(100, 149, 237, 255)',
      'Test3\nline2': 'rgba(143, 188, 139, 255)'
    };
    const getColor = function(context) {
      const {chart, datasetIndex, dataIndex} = context;
      const dataset =  chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
      const data = dataset.data[dataIndex];
      return colors[data.y];
    }

    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: getColor,
                borderColor: getColor,
                barPercentage: 0.8,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                data: [{
                    y: 'Test1\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:06:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip1'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test1\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:18:00', '2022-09-29T16:25:10'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip2'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test1\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:31:00', '2022-09-29T16:50:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip3'
                },{
                    y: 'Test2\nline2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:03:03', '2022-09-29T16:13:06' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip4'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2\nline2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:16:03', '2022-09-29T16:19:06' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip5'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2\nline2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:20:37', '2022-09-29T16:30:40' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip8'
                },{
                    y: 'Test2\nline2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:35:51', '2022-09-29T16:48:54' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip6'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test2\nline2',
                    x: [ '2022-09-29T16:49:51', '2022-09-29T16:58:54' ],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip7'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:00:00', '2022-09-29T16:05:02'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip9'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:12:00', '2022-09-29T16:30:10'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip10'
                }, {
                    y: 'Test3\nline2',
                    x: ['2022-09-29T16:40:00', '2022-09-29T16:55:48'],
                    tooltip: 'Tooltip11'
                }]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            animation: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    stacked: true,
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute'
                    },
                    min: new Date('2022-09-29T16:00:00'),
                    max: new Date('2022-09-29T16:55:48'),
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 70,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        minRotation: -90,
                        maxRotation: -90
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value, index, labels) {
                            return this.getLabelForValue(value).split('\n');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                   legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    yAlign: 'bottom',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: (context) => {
                            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].tooltip;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('log_chart'),
      config
    );
</script>
```